# Grouping With Header in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table with the following columns and data

- Category Item Price Tax
- A I1 1.00 .01
- A I2 2.22 .02
- B I3 3.33 0.3

I want to group on Category and have the details below such as:

- Category/Item Price Tax
- A
- I1 1.00 .01
- I2 2.22 .02
- B
- I3 3.33 .03

I want the category to have its own row then the detail rows below with the item in the same column as the Category.

The output that is desired is:

- Category - Item | Price | Tax
- A         |       |
- I1        | 1.00  | .01
- I2        | 2.22  | .02
- B         |       |
- I3        | 3.33  | .03

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run through the new Report Wizard, select Tabular Report Type, Move the category field to the group and then the rest of your columns to the details.  Select a stepped format in the next page then Select finish.

Now on the generated report should look how u want.  And/or u can move the fields to look how u want now.

per the comments

you can move the Item from the second column and put it under the first column in that row and then delete the item column so right now it looks something like this but leaving all the grouping in tact.

```
    Category | Item | Price | Tax
    [category]
               [item]  [price] [tax]
```

change it to look like this

```
    Category / Item | Price | Tax
    [category]  
    [item]            [price]  [tax]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it on an existing report without the wizard?

Comment: That doesn't format it how I expected.  What I end up with is
Category | Item | Price | Tax
  A      |      |       |
         |  I1  |  1.00 | .01
         |  I2  |  2.22 | .02
  B      |      |       |
         |  I3  |  3.33 | .03

What I expected was
Category Item | Price | Tax
    A         |       |
    I1        |  1.00 | .01
    I2        |  2.22 | .02
    B         |       |
    I3        |  3.33 | .03

Does that make sense?

Comment: I think so, i added some more to my first post hopefully that clears up either what i am or am not understanding from the initial question